# Debugging DLL Called With CeRapiInvoke

Tags: dll, windows-mobile, rapi

I'm trying to debug into a C dll that is invoked on a Windows Mobile device using CeRapiInvoke() (Technically RAPI.Invoke() from OpenNETCF) from a Windows box.  I'm very familiar with attaching to a process that is already running to debug a loaded dll (I've done it many time with Windows Mobile services) but I can't seem to figure out what process is actually running the dll.  Even when running the Remote Process Viewer I don't see any new processes pop up, so it must be something that is already running... Any ideas as to which process to attach to in order to debug into the dll when invoked?

Edit:  After trying to attach to several different processes I found that it was "rapiclnt.exd" that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rapiclnt.exe is the process which loads the RAPI dlls. Read this for more on debugging RAPI dlls.

http://knowledgepointer.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/debugging-rapi-dlls/